# Apache fails to serve request or pauses for extended period of time

Tags: apache-2.2, php, localhost, openssl, virtualhost

At seeming random intervals, my page requests will timeout. It happens the most to me when I am working on either a Drupal 7 project or a CodeIgniter project.

Chrome gives me the error `Error 7 (net::ERR_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.` and suggests that I refresh the page (very helpful!).

I am using SSL on the CI project but I believe I have pretty well ruled out the possibility that it is the issue as I have double checked my configuration and I have the same problem on the D7 project which does not use SSL.

Software stack:

- Apache 2.2.19 downloaded from [ApacheLounge](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/). (VC9)
- PHP 5.3.6 (VC9)

Resarting Apache doesn't seem to help the situation and I am at a loss to know what to try next. Any and all suggestions and help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the requests that are timing out anywhere in the apache log files?

Comment: There is no record in the log files of any activity.

Comment: After carefully monitoring this issue for a while, It seems likely that this is a network issue of some sort. Any suggestions how to debug and what to try next?

Answer (score 0):

If there's nothing in your log files, and you've got debug logging turned on, then the problem is that the requests aren't getting to Apache.  Check your network.

Comment: I set `LogLevel debug` Is that all?

Comment: It must be a network issue, nothing is hitting the log.